# Where to find Mac pictures after a computer hard drive crash?

Tags: linux, mac, osx-yosemite, photos

This is my problem, my computer's hard drive crashed and I am currently using Linux to try and find my photos and back them up, but I can't find the file where most of the photos are. I did find some photos in the iPhoto library, but it's just one folder from 2011.

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/$USER/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary`

Comment: I used iPhotos. There's no Photos folder in the Pictures folder.